# Node JS - No such file?

Tags: node.js, file, error-handling, filestream, chmod

I'm using this piece of code to delete a file on demand

```
{
...
    fs.access(path, (err)=> err || fs.unlink(path));    
...
}
```

I got this error

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'C:\ ... '
>       at Error (native)

Which makes no sense to me as I literally just checked for the files existence before attempting the unlink - I have a feeling something weird's going on behind the scenes like file locking.

How do I rectify this error?

Also, do I need to lock the file myself before I attempt to delete, to guarantee a robust and safe delete. I won't be there to manually delete the file and restart the server every time a user tries to delete their file.

Comment: *"I literally just checked for the files existence before attempting the unlink"* - Don't do that, this is bad practice. Don't do file existence checks (they have been deprecated for a reason). Simply unlink and catch the error, if any.

Comment: should I unlink recursively until it works

Comment: wont errors happen, im confused

Comment: In the split-second between when you made an "exists" check and when you call unlink, the file might already be gone due to external factors. Irrelevant if that is likely for *your* application, it's still technically possible. Therefore, "exists" checks are generally  worthless. Simply doing what you want to do (read, write, delete) and handling errors as they occur is the only useful strategy with file system interactions.

Comment: should i keep trying to delete until it deletes

Comment: Isn't that what you would otherwise also do? The exists check does not really change anything in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling fs.access before write or delete is not recommended.  Please check the below link
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback

```
Using fs.access() to check for the accessibility of a file before calling fs.open(), fs.readFile() or fs.writeFile() is not recommended. Doing so introduces a race condition, since other processes may change the file's state between the two calls. Instead, user code should open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the file is not accessible.
```